# Pause and resume loop in C

Tags: c, loops, resume

I am writing a game code in C which involves display of numbers with a time gap entered by the user.

```
srand ( time(NULL) ); //this avoids generating the same random number everytime
start:
    mySleep(userdelay);
    printf("\n\n\a\t%d",rand()%90); //prints random numbers with the time delay entered by the user.
goto start;
```

So I just wanted to know how to pause this loop with user input like "Press 1 to pause" and resume the same loop with user input like "Press 2 to resume".

Thanx in advance!

Comment: you should use `while` instead of the `goto` which is bad practice when it's not necessary...

Comment: hmm yes. coz i want the loop till the user exits the program

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this may be the best way, but it could be one working way. Try  using  a while loop  in your command console:

```
int main(){
    int i;
    scanf("%d",&i)
    switch(i){
        case 1: while(i != 2){
                    sleep(1); //or define duration by a variable if time should be "dynamic"
                    scanf("%d",&i);
                    break;
                }
    }
}
```

I hope you get an idea of the idea.

EDIT:

If you want  the user to input data until "exit key" a while loop is much bether than goto. If you are not familiar with `switch(){}` i advice you to take a look [here](http://cprogramminglanguage.net/404.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/_sites/cprogramminglanguage.net/c-switch-statement.aspx).

Comment: I wouldn't use scanf for user input. At the very least you should check the return value.